# MongoDB: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference

Tags: mongodb

I have installed the following components (On 10 ubuntu servers):

1. config replica set (3 nodes)
2. 2 shards(replica set of 3 nodes)
3. Mongos

I created a new database and a collection and tried to shard it, but I get an error. Checking the logs I figured the following:

```
2017-01-10T16:43:24.947+0200 W COMMAND  [conn4] couldn't move chunk ns: David.drone, shard: rs2, lastmod: 1|0||5874f2e4345e33f450ccb222, min: { _id: MinKey }, max: { _id: 0 } to shard sh1:sh1/prodSh1Node1:27017,prodSh1Node2:27017,prodSh1Node3:27017 while sharding collection David.drone :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: could not get updated shard list from config server due to could not find host matching read preference { mode: "nearest" } for set cfg-RepSet
2017-01-10T16:43:45.040+0200 I SHARDING [conn4] Split chunk { splitChunk: "David.drone", configdb: confSet/prodConf1:47017,prodConf2:47017,prodConf3:47017", from: "sh2", keyPattern: { _id: "hashed" }, shardVersion: [ Timestamp 1000|1, ObjectId('5874f2e4345e33f450ccb222') ], min: { _id: MinKey }, max: { _id: 0 }, chunkVersion: [ Timestamp 1000|0, ObjectId('5874f2e4345e33f450ccb222') ], splitKeys: [ { _id: -4611686018427387902 } ] } failed :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set confSet
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks, just for you to know-

Eventually, we figured out one of the components was not configured to recognize the Config Shard. We re-configured it and it worked out.

Comment: By the way - the missing part was one of the replicas not recognizing one of the config servers

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you elaborate more, what did you change?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some members of your replica sets are unavailable. You could try to reconfigure the replica set. See [this manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/) for more info.